# ['Firebase/Firebase.h' file not found]My app work on simulator but it doesn't work on my iphone 6 plus

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase

when I use simulator to run my code, it finely works. However, when it run on my iphone 6 plus the fellowing errors occur.

[image]

Also these two file turn red.

[image]

ps.:I use Xcode 7.3 and 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.1'. All of these are latest version.

Comment: Please don't just post images of XCode as they're inherently non-searchable. Instead post the actual error message and the code that causes the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the library linked as well as imported:

- Go to the project file list in the left of Xcode and select the project.
- Select the Target.
- In the 'General' section scroll down to 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries'
- Check if Firebase SDK is listed, if not click '+' and add it.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now. But the fellow warning occur.
(null): Directory not found for option '-F/Users/Anthony/Documents/beyond copy/build/Debug-iphoneos'

Comment: Glad it worked! Try going to the Product menu up in the menu bar, select 'Product'. Then hold down the alt/option key and choose Clean Build Folder... That should remove any cached build. Then do a build and it should recreate the build files with the new settings.

Comment: It doesn't work. Seems it really missed a file named [bulid/Debug-iphoneos]

Comment: @Cocoadelica: sir firebase not found in list can you tell me why not show in  list?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase might've not been installed in your project. Make sure you install it. [Here's a link to the firebase docs.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that including the library as a pod install directly helps dynamic libraries. For example, for Firebase:

```
pod 'RNFirebase', :path => 'path/to/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'
```

Changing or hardcoding `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` did not help me.

If the error ever recurs, it's not necessary to `rm -rf node_modules` nor delete the pod file etc - I found it useful to clear the cache.

For react-native, I run

```
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-*
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-*
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* 
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* 
    rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*
    rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache"
    npm start -- --reset-cache
```

For Xcode I remove folders in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 0):

### For swift:

```swift
import Firebase

FirebaseApp.configure()
```

For Objective C:

```
@import Firebase;

[FIRApp configure];
```